# Where is this room located on the map?

Tags: teslagrad

Recently, I have managed to collect all scrolls and complete the game. But still, there seems to be a room I haven't encountered:

[image: hidden room?]

This screenshot can be found at the game's official site (image #2 in the [gallery](https://www.teslagrad.com/#gallery)). It's among other screenshots of known rooms, therefore it would seem that I just managed to miss it somehow. It seems to be part of the giant tree room.

I have done some research and found no mention of this place online. Can it be found somewhere on the map or is it not located anywhere? If it exists, where can it be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the extra levels that was included as exclusive bonus content for the XBox One release of Teslagrad.

Earlier this month, Rain Games released Teslagrad Remastered for Steam, Switch, PS4, PS5, XBox One, and XBox Series X, which also includes these bonus levels, accessible behind the scroll vault once you defeat the Orb boss.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Teslagrad remastered is next on my play list right now actually :)